# How to convert any[] to observable<any[]> in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have a variable `countryList : any[]` which has following data:

```
[
  {"countrycode":"SH","countryname":"Saint Helena"},
  {"countrycode":"KN","countryname":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"},   
  {"countrycode":"LC","countryname":"Saint Lucia"},   
  {"countrycode":"IS","countryname":"Iceland"}, 
  {"countrycode":"IN","countryname":"India"},  
  {"countrycode":"ID","countryname":"Indonesia"},  
  {"countrycode":"IR","countryname":"Iran (Islamic Republic of)"},   
  {"countrycode":"IQ","countryname":"Iraq"},    
  {"countrycode":"IE","countryname":"Ireland"},    
  {"countrycode":"IM","countryname":"Isle of Man"}, 
  {"countrycode":"IL","countryname":"Israel"}, 
  {"countrycode":"SH","countryname":"Saint Helena"},
  {"countrycode":"KN","countryname":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"}, 
  {"countrycode":"LC","countryname":"Saint Lucia"},
  {"countrycode":"ZM","countryname":"Zambia"},
  {"countrycode":"ZW","countryname":"Zimbabwe"}
]
```

I want to convert it into observable

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `of` for return in `observable` in angular 6.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

someFunction(){
    return of([
        { "countrycode": "SH", "countryname": "Saint Helena" }, 
        { "countrycode": "KN", "countryname": "Saint Kitts and Nevis" }, 
        { "countrycode": "LC", "countryname": "Saint Lucia" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IS", "countryname": "Iceland" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IN", "countryname": "India" }, 
        { "countrycode": "ID", "countryname": "Indonesia" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IR", "countryname": "Iran (Islamic Republic of)" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IQ", "countryname": "Iraq" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IE", "countryname": "Ireland" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IM", "countryname": "Isle of Man" }, 
        { "countrycode": "IL", "countryname": "Israel" }, 
        { "countrycode": "SH", "countryname": "Saint Helena" }, 
        { "countrycode": "KN", "countryname": "Saint Kitts and Nevis" }, 
        { "countrycode": "LC", "countryname": "Saint Lucia" }, 
        { "countrycode": "ZM", "countryname": "Zambia" }, 
        { "countrycode": "ZW", "countryname": "Zimbabwe" }
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using rxjs 6, you can simply use:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// ...

let obs = of([
     {"countrycode":"SH","countryname":"Saint Helena"},
     {"countrycode":"KN","countryname":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"},
     // etc... 
])
```

If you're using an older version, replace `of` with `Observable.of`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `of` operator from `rxjs` like this: `return of(countryList)`

Answer (score 0):

To convert any[] to Observable(any[]) you can use **of function** if you are using rxjs package.

**In component.ts**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// Other imports

let observableData = of([
{"countrycode":"SH","countryname":"Saint 
Helena"},
{"countrycode":"KN","countryname":"Saint 
Kitts and Nevis"},
{"countrycode":"Ky","countryname":"Saint 
Kitt and Nevis"}

])
```

refer this [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html)